# Kafka throwing "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have developed Kafka consumer application using `spring-kafka` library and used default consumer configurations with Manual commits.

I am running two instances of application listening to two different Kafka topics. While performing load testing I observed that I am getting below error in only one of the application for higher load:

```
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 

    This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, 
    which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 

    You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches 
    returned in poll() with max.poll.records.


org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: 
    Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 

    This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, 
    which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 


You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    \n org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:725)
```

I read several articles and found if consumer spending to much time in processing message and broker is not getting information about consumer liveliness then consumer rebalancing happens and above exception will be thrown for uncommited messages.

I have resolved above error by setting max.poll.interval.ms to INEGER.MAX_VALUE.
But I am wondering why I am getting above error only in one of instance and why other instance working as expected for higher loads.

Can anyone please share correct root cause and ideal value for `max.poll.interval.ms` or appropriate solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

One cause for this could be that your `poll()` takes a lot of messages, and that's why it takes a lot of time to process all of them.
**max.poll.records** defines the maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.
According to [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html), it's default is 500.
You can try to set that to something smaller, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Also consider to upgrade to the latest Spring Kafka and Apache Kafka per se: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn. The rebalance because of slow listener has been fixed since Kafka `0.10.1`: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread

Comment: I agree with it... But why I am not facing same problem with other instance listening to different topic

Comment: @ASHISHGUPTA did you measure the load on other instance like how many message it pulled and how log it took to process. May be other instance is reading some low traffic partition.

Comment: @mrnakumar I checked other instance. It is pulling all messages and processed within 2-3 minutes which is less than default max.poll.interval.ms (5 minutes)

Comment: @ASHISHGUPTA so now we know why other instance was not seeing the same error. As next step you might want to set max poll interval config as per below formula: max(300000,max(processing_time_of_first_instance, processing_time_of_second_instance)). This means set it equal to the time taken by longest processing loop but make it no less than default.

Comment: @mrnakumar Correct but processing time for single message taken by both instance is exactly the same. So wondering for higher load one instance is working properly with default configuration and other is not working

Comment: @ASHISHGUPTA yes but one instance is pulling less records than other. Did you check if each call to poll returns same number of records in both instances?

Comment: @ASHISHGUPTA Also when you know the processing time of a single record then multiply it by max.poll.records and this can be your max.poll.interval.ms.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the suggestion by Yoav, if reducing the batch size is not an option, you can also try to increase the value for `max.poll.interval.ms`. From the Kafka docs:

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer
>   group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time
>   that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll()
>   is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is
>   considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign
>   the partitions to another member.

Comment: I changed max.poll.interval.ms to Integer.MAX_VALUE and it worked. But wanted to know what is pros and cons of setting it to larger value.

Comment: You can assure that your consumers are only declared dead if the actual processing time exceed your expected processing time. The value should be the expected maximum processing time. If the value is too low, then your consumers are declared dead too early and rebalanced too often. If the value is too high, then the consumer might already be dead but it will not be rebalanced before the actual processing time exceed `max.poll.interval.ms`.  You have to fine tune the property to achieve the best performance. You can benchmark to estimate the WCET for your consumer.

Answer (score 0):

**Set max.poll.interval.ms  minimum 5000000 in you properties like**

```
consumer.set("max.poll.interval.ms","5000000");
consumer.set("max.poll.records","2");
consumer.set("session.time.out.ms","30000"); 
consumer.set("heartbeat.interval.ms","25000");
```

Hope that: -
it will help you....